# Getting error in client-server programming

Tags: java, sockets, networking, distributed-computing

I have created client Server program in java. While I run program I should get port number and IP address but I am getting an error while I run Client.java. Below is my both files.

Server.java

```
package serverpro;


import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect.to;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Server extends Thread  {

public static final int PORT_NUMBER = 12345;
protected Socket socket;

public static void main(String[] args) {
  ServerSocket server = null;
  try {
     server = new ServerSocket(PORT_NUMBER);
     while (true) {
        new Server(server.accept());
     }
  }
  catch(IOException ex) {
     System.out.println("Unable to start server or acccept connections ");
     System.exit(1);
  }
  finally {
     try {
        server.close();
     }
     catch(IOException ex) {
        // not much can be done: log the error
        // exits since this is the end of main
     }
  }
 }

 private Server(Socket socket) {
  this.socket = socket;
  start();
}

 // the server services client requests in the run method
  public void run() {
  InputStream in = null;
  OutputStream out = null;

    BufferedReader inReader = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(in));
  // the constructor argument “true” enables auto-flushing
  PrintWriter outWriter = new PrintWriter(out, true);
  outWriter.println("Echo server: enter bye to exit.");

  //outWriter.println(“Echo server: enter ‘bye’ to exit.”);
  while (true) {
  // readLine blocks until a line-terminated string is available
  String inLine;
      try {
          inLine = inReader.readLine();
      } catch (IOException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
  // readLine returns null if the client just presses <return>

  try {
     in = socket.getInputStream();
     out = socket.getOutputStream();
     // ... do useful stuff ...
  }
  catch(IOException ex) {
     System.out.println("Unable to get Stream from ");
  }
  finally {
     try {
        in.close();
        out.close();
        socket.close();
     }
     catch(IOException ex) {
        // not much can be done: log the error
     }
     }
     }
  }
 }
```

Client.java

```
package serverpro;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client {
 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
  new Client(args[0]);
 }

  public Client(String host) throws IOException {
  Socket socket;
  try {
    socket = new Socket(host, Server.PORT_NUMBER);
  }
  catch(UnknownHostException ex) {
     System.out.println(host + " is not a valid host name.");
     return;
  }
  catch(IOException ex) {
     System.out.println("Error connecting with" + host);
     return;
  }
  // … initialize model, GUI, etc. ...
  InputStream in = null;
  OutputStream out = null;
  try {
     in = socket.getInputStream();
     out = socket.getOutputStream();
     // ... do useful stuff ...
  }
  finally {
     try {
        in.close();
        out.close();
        socket.close();
     }
     catch(IOException ex) {
        // not much can be done ...
     }
  } 
 }
```

}

Here is the error code I am getting while running client.java file

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at serverpro.Client.main(Client.java:13)
/Users/Puja Dudhat/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2/executor- snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: when you run Client class, r u passing required command-line argument?

Comment: It should run automatically without passing command line argument. how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not passing required command-line argument. When I ran this code it did run fine, provided the argument required is passed or hard-coded; namely:

```
public static void main(**String args[]**) throws IOException {
    new Client(**args[0]**);
}
```

Comment: It should run automatically without passing command line argument. how to do that ?

Comment: where do I need to make changes. Can you please say in detail. Today is my submission for this projrct.  and I am getting an error

Answer (score 0):

Your code expects one argument passed into the main method, which appears to be your client port, stored at `args[0]`. Therefore, you have to provide  one to the main method. An example for setting port=12345:

```
java Server 12345
```

If you'd need more arguments, (e.g. a value at `args[1]`), then simply add another argument when launching main:

```
java Server 12345 secondArg
```

Comment: where do I need to make changes. can you please exactly point out ? and can you please write whole line ?

Comment: I already wrote the line. When you launch the application, you need to provide the arguments. My example was assuming you are running from the command line. If you're doing it from an IDE like Eclipse, you'll have to find where in its GUI to set Java Program Arguments. If it's other code calling the main method, then clearly that caller needs to specify an argument, e.g., `new Server(new String[]{12345});`

Comment: hello like when I run the program it should show ip address of host and port number without entering manually anything. to make that change what do I need to do?

Comment: You should fix your script -- or whatever it is -- that launches the JVM with Server as its entry point. It's clearly not adding program arguments for IP/port.

Comment: So what  changes do I need to make in order to do that ?

Comment: That's specific to your environment and off-topic here. I literally gave you the command to run, so now you have to determine where to use it. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

if you are running both server and client on same machine then you can pass **localhost** as command line argument

java Client localhost

Alternatively, you can hard code host value(note : this is not good practice though),

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    new Client("localhost");
}
```

Also as a suggestion, you can use ide like eclipse or intellij to debug your code step by step. you can go through online video tutorials for java and many are available on youtube